# Is this a plunge router?

Tags: routers

This is a second hand router that I would like to buy. I am not sure if by the description on the package this is a plunge router or not
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is a plunge router. Note in particular the second photo,which shows the adjustable depth stop rod and the turret beneath it which allows progressively stepping the bit deeper in successive passes until it reaches the intended depth.

The fact that the base is attached via two smooth rods that guide the plunge also makes this fairly obvious.

Comment: how about fixed router? Can we say it is a fixed router? If it came with a table (combo) does it make it a fixed router too ?

Comment: Plunge routers can be "fixed" at a certain height, but as answered, it really is a plunge router... Table doesn't change anything.

Comment: Yes I marked the question as valid but I was curious if this is a fixed router as well. What exactly would make a router fixed?

Comment: Above I meant the answer

Comment: @user2059078: a fixed router would have virtually no provision for adjusting the depth of cut while operating. They are essentially high speed motors with handles and that's mostly it. Do image searches for plunge and fixed router and you should see some common differences.

Comment: Google "PORTER-CABLE 893PK" (as an example; not an endorsement, though I do happen to own about 7 P-C routers...) to see how one motor can fit two different bases to be either a plunge or a fixed router.

Comment: And FWIW, the one you pictured would never fit into a fixed base.